# Указатель и динамическая память C++

Tags: c++, указатели

```
class CStrok
{
   public:
   char* m_pstr;
};

void main()
{
   CStrok a;
   CStrok b;
   a.m_pstr = new char[4];
   a.m_pstr = "one";
   b = a;
   b.m_pstr = "two";
   cout << b.m_pstr << endl;
   cout << a.m_pstr << endl;
   return;
}
```

Если я правильно понял указатели, то при b = a копируется адрес строки "one" из переменной а в переменную b, и при присвоении указателю b иной строки, строка в a тоже должна измениться т.к. и указатели переменных а и b указывают на один адрес. Однако при выводе строк, они оказываются разными. Что не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в программе утечка памяти. Смотрите - здесь вы выделили где-то в памяти 4 байта и передали указатель в `a.m_pstr`:

```
a.m_pstr = new char[4];
```

И тут же благополучно **переписали** его адресом строки `"one"`, т.е. первый указатель потеряли, и вам его уже никогда не освободить.

```
a.m_pstr = "one";
```

Кстати, если вы хотели **скопировать** строку в выделенную память, надо было использовать что-то вроде `strcpy`. И еще - учтите, что *строковый литерал константен*, так что вы не должны его менять, например, нельзя писать `a.m_pstr[0] = 'q'`.

```
b = a;
```

Вы всего лишь скопировали *адрес* из переменной в `a` в `b`. Они сейчас указывают на одну и ту же строку.

```
b.m_pstr = "two";
```

А теперь переменная `a` хранит старый адрес, а переменная `b` получает адрес строки `"two"`. Поэтому при выводе вы выводите две разные строки.

Answer (score 2):

> Если я правильно понял указатели, то при b = a копируется адрес строки
> "one" из переменной а в переменную b

Правильно

> и при присвоении указателю b иной строки, строка в a тоже должна
> измениться т.к. и указатели переменных а и b указывают на один адрес.

Нет, после присваивания другой строки `a` и `b` теперь указывают на разные адреса. Если бы они указывали на один адрес, и значение объекта по адресу вы поменяли бы, тогда и в a, и в b поменялось – ведь один и тот же объект.

> Однако при выводе строк, они оказываются разными. Что не так ?

Все правильно.